# installing Gallery mod in PHPBB

Tags: module, gallery, phpbb3

I tried to install the mod manually, and I have followed the instruction carefully but still I am getting this error! any idea about this?

I went to the `install/index.php` after editing all the files and copying all the folder with contents to its correct place

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

manual work are error prone

install `automod` for phpbb3 or `easymod` for phpbb2

and then install gallery via `automod` or `easymod`